# Error in Automation of uploading SFTP file of WinSCP using batch script

Tags: batch-file, sftp, file-transfer, winscp

I am very new to both WinSCP and batch file scripting. So excuse me  if this question is very basic.
I am trying to upload file from my local folder to remote folder using batch file. The name of the file changes every week. I am facing 2 problems.

1. I am using below code in batch file to upload a file to WinSCP

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /command ^
    open sftp://descartes:z*******s@sftp.psdataservices.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 ******=" ^
    "lcd  C:\Users\kajal.jain\Downloads\New folder" ^
    "cd /" ^
    "put Week 7 2022 Portal Data" ^
    "exit"
```

I am getting below error.

```
Unknown command 'lcd  C:\Users\kajal.jain\Downloads\New folder'.
Same for cd
```

2. As the name of file to be uploaded changes every week. How can I automate it in the Put command?

Comment: You are missing a double quote before the `OPEN` command. You also need to quote file paths and folder paths with spaces like so. `"put ""Week 7 2022 Portal Data"""`

Comment: I'd recommend using the `/script` option and a separate file instead of trying to type everything out on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Add quotes!** Since WinSCP needs all its commands with spaces surrounded by double-quotes ([see syntax reference here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax)), I'd first put some around that `open ...` command, and then around other paths in your `lcd` and `put` commands. You can use *two* double-quotes to mean a literal `"` in your command.
2. **Pass in a filename.** You can use `%1` to refer to the first command-line argument to this batch file. So if you save the script below as "upload.bat"...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://descartes:z*******s@sftp.psdataservices.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 1024 ******=""" ^
    "lcd  ""C:\Users\kajal.jain\Downloads\New folder""" ^
    "cd /" ^
    "put %1" ^
    "exit"
```

...then from the command line you could type

```
upload "Week 7 2022 Portal Data"
```

to have it upload that file (quotes are important there too).

Another option--and I'll leave it to you to research--if you didn't want to give it a filename at all, you could explore using the `SET` command so it'd do something like always looking for and uploading a file named with today's date. [More info here on batch arguments and SET](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_variables.htm).